# TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateUrl' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

When I am trying to browse a url which is not in $routeProvider I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateUrl' of undefined
```

here is the js code

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/MY/home/home',
        controller: function($scope) {
            //my custom code
        }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming your code is wrapped inside

```
myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  //your code here
}]);
```

this should work. maybe you could show what the path to your template looks like because it might just be a typo in the path.