# The $routeProvider in Angular can't be found in undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm following [a guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par) on how to include AngularJS in a MVC project and I got to the point where I'm connecting my controllers (the section's name is *Routing*).

It seems not to work and when I open the console, I see the following error message.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$routeProvider' of undefined

I've checked all the files in the solution for that string and the only usage of it is in the file where I registered my module. It looks like this.

```
var CoolApp = angular.module('CoolApp', ["ngRoute"]);
CoolApp.controller('CoolController', CoolController);

var configFunction = function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/one", { templateUrl: "angularRoute/first" })
    .when("/two", { templateUrl: "angularRoute/second" })
    .when("/thr", { templateUrl: "angularRoute/third" });
}

configFunction.$inject["$routeProvider"];
CoolApp.config(configFunction);
```

I have MVC controller class named *AngularRouteController* and as far I can see, the only place where I'm "dotting" the *$routeProvider* is in *when* statements. Commenting them out doesn't resolve my issue, though. Instead, the line that **seems** to be the cause of the error is this one.

```
configFunction.$inject["$routeProvider"];
```

Due to my ignorance with Angular, I can't see why. As a consequence, I have no idea how to solve the problem. Any suggestions would be welcome. I've googled the issue but that didn't give me anything useful (as far I could judge).

The closest hits I've got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841696/typeerror-cannot-read-property-templateurl-of-undefined) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929696/angularjs-routing-cannot-read-property-path-of-undefined) and they didn't make me any wiser. Not even sure if those are relevant to my problem.

I've made sure that I reference the routing package of Angular separately as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172558/cannot-inject-routeprovider-in-angular). Should I skip *ngRoute* and go for *ui.router*? Not sure what that changes for the guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to change that line to:

```
configFunction.$inject = [
    "$routeProvider"
];
```

Comment: I might be tired and cranky of all the trouble-shooting... I can't see any difference between your suggestion and what I've got already. Except for the line-breaks and that can't be the issue, right?

Comment: @AndyJ Try it anyway, I also added an = sign ;-)

Comment: I'm telling you, bro - I've been looking at the lines (yours and mine) for ten minutes and **still** didn't see the difference. In addition to tired and cranky I probably should add stupid and blind, hahaha. As you pointed out - the equality sign did the trick. Now I'm getting another error but that's for me to resolve. Thanks!